# Is this General Reference?

Tags: discussion, scope, closing-questions, general-reference

[Why was Count Dooku not given the title "Darth"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9899/why-was-count-dooku-not-given-the-word-darth)

Googling for "[count dooku darth](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=count%20dooku%20darth&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=a2f2e0712ab20a9e&biw=1024&bih=583&pf=p&pdl=500)" brings up as the very first link+blurb:

> Count Dooku - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
>   en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_Dooku
>   **Count Dooku / Darth Tyranus**. Star Wars character. Christopher Lee ... Count Dooku

However, I'm the only one who voted to close as general reference.

Is it just me not getting the GR rules, or merely not enough people online?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a close reason that was abandoned long ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see the answer to the question in the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_Dooku) nor in the first Google hits. Ok, Dooku did have a Darth name, but why wasn't he known by it? The [Star Wars wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dooku) has an extended biography that may contain the answer (something about using his nobility status for a power base, I think), but it could use a summary targeted to this specific issue.

On the other hand, given that the question has a massively upvoted accepted answer which only mentions the existence of the Darth name and does not go into the why at all, this Q&A is not providing any new content on the Internet or making any content more accessible. This is the very point of the general reference close reason: if we're not improving on Wikipedia, the thread is a waste of time. I say kill it, and let the question be reasked (insisting on a proper answer) if someone cares.

Comment: Thanks. what did you search on? My Q showed the Wikipedia blurb straight from Google hits (not even Wiki itself), you must have had a different search.

Comment: @DVK I used the same search, and a few variations which didn't turn up anything more relevant. I see the blurb “Count Dooku / Darth Tyranus. Star Wars character. Christopher Lee ... Count Dooku is a fictional character from the Star Wars universe. Dooku is one of the main” for WP; this gives the Darth name but does not say anything about why.

Comment: Since the Q was 'Why was Count Dooku not given the word "Darth"?'  - the fact that he WAS given a name as the blurb shows answers the question 100%, IMHO

Comment: I felt silly when that thirty-second answer earned so much rep and some badges, particularly since I haven't otherwise really contributed to this site. No objection here.

Comment: So what you're saying is we should all stop wasting our time here and edit Wikipedia instead.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard - No, but the FAQ for the site explicitly says that you need to show effort in research. This question shows none.

Answer (score 5):

I agree its general reference if you found it with google and answered on Wikipedia.

I think some people don't at least research a little before posting.

Answer (score -8):

I've flagged it as "general research". Searching for "Count Dooku Darth" (without the quotes) answers the main question in **all top 10 search results** on google. The top 3 results even give the answer on the first line.

[image]

Any level of research whatsoever would have immediately yielded the result. As far as I'm concerned this sort of question borders on trolling

You might as well ask who Luke's father is.

Comment: We no longer close questions due to "General Reference". And it's not a bad question otherwise

Comment: @SSumner - It borders on trolling IMHO.

Comment: "General Reference" used to be one of the preexisting close reasons (like "too broad" and "primarily opinion-based" are nowadays).  It was removed a long time ago, and is no longer a valid reason to close questions (although downvoting is still fair game).

Comment: @dvk - As I said, this question goes beyond "general reference". Even the most casual viewing of the film would have revealed the answer, as would a simple google search for the character's name.

Comment: @Richard I'm not DVK.  And even back when General Reference was around, Google didn't count, because it culls results based on your location and prior searches.  It only applied to Wikipedia and IMDB (and maybe ISFDB, can't remember) - sites that were reliable and built for a specific purpose that we could use General Reference akin to how closing as duplicates points to the answer being somewhere else.

Comment: @Richard - trolling implies deliberate attempt to damage. Throwing such an accusation reqiures a solid proof of INTENT of damage.

Comment: Also, I wonder who Luke's father **really** is. I STILL maintain it's Obi-Wan. Have you seen how jealous Anakin was in ROTS?

Comment: We don't require having watched, read or listened to source material, we don't have *too localized* or *general reference* close reasons. Downvote it to oblivion if you want, but there is no legitimate reason to close this.

Comment: Also, [Google is not general reference](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/google-is-not-general-reference). Just saying.

Comment: @Martha - Wrong stack, but good point.