# Questions that largely have the same answer?

Tags: discussion

This question is similar to [Should all questions without explicit canon answers be closed?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/should-all-questions-without-explicit-canon-answers-be-closed), except that I'm going a step further in asking about topics where the lack of canon makes most questions unanswerable, or open to answers along the lines of "there is no answer".

There is a specific tag that I have in mind: [mst3k](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mst3k), where a lot of questions could have the same answer as the accepted answer to [What is the purpose of The Satellite of Love?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8740)

They might be different questions, but because of the nature of the show and the deliberate lack of canon surrounding it, I could foresee a lot of questions being answered with almost an exact copy-and-paste of the accepted answer to the question above.

For example, I might ask

> Why was the Satellite of Love shaped like a bone? Was there a reason for this given in-universe?

Now, I don't know the answer to this question, and it might have a legitimate answer. However, my instincts are telling me that the real answer is going to be some form of

> If you're wondering how he eats and breathes  
>   And other science facts (LA LA LA) 
>   Just repeat to yourself it's just a show 
>   I should really just relax

So should we allow these questions? I would say yes, according to the [meta question I linked above](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/should-all-questions-without-explicit-canon-answers-be-closed), except we could end up with 100 [mst3k](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mst3k) questions with exactly the same answer.

Should tags like this have it noted in their wiki that some forms of questions are not likely to be answerable?

---

Note that MST3K is just an example, and there could be plenty of others in the same boat.

Answer (score 9):

### No, they should not be closed.

Although a common rubrick for identifying duplicate questions is "are the answers the same to each?", in this case you've chosen an answer so broad that it could apply to every question on the site.

Answers which say "It's just fiction, stop trying to read into it" are almost universally downvoted, so answers of the type you're suggesting wouldn't be accepted by the citizen gestalt in the first place. This makes sense, because it's denying what the site is all about in the first place!

The vast majority of non-ID questions on this site are rooted in speculation and have no definitive canon answer (although they may be based on extrapolation from canon, that is still speculation). Even many of the ones *with* canon answers could easily also be answered by saying "It's just a work of fiction, stop worrying about this stuff."

Using the MST3K mantra as a whole answer trivializes the question and implies that both the question and this site are worthy of casual dismissal. This is a rabbit hole I think we should be loathe to start down.

Remember, we've [talked about "trivial questions" before](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3073/13941).

### If a question is unanswerable, there are two good answers it can have.

The first is an answer which demonstrates that the question is unanswerable, by providing evidence or context.

The second is no answer at all.

"Answers" which are just the poster's opinion that the question is unanswerable beg for support.

You're right that the MST3K mantra *could* be used to answer every [mst3k](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mst3k) question, but for the majority of them it would be a **bad answer** and should be downvoted.